# How to get Mouse event from a view while a TextField is first responder

Tags: macos, textfield, first-responder, mousedown

I'm working on a graphic editor application, and I would like to insert tokens in my textfield when user select graphic items.

The problem is that I don't receive mouse down event when the textfield is firstResponder.

Is there a way to get events while keeping the textfield first responder ?

Comment: You could try method swizzling on the `currentEditor` of your `NSTextField`